# emacs 24.3 ignoring foreground/background color with color-theme?

Tags: emacs

I've been using color-theme for quite awhile to set colors in my .emacs:

```
(defun custom-theme ()
  (interactive)
  (color-theme-install
   '(custom-theme
     ((background-color . "black")
      (background-mode  . dark)
      (border-color     . "#0d1b2b")
      (cursor-color     . "#fce94f")
      (foreground-color . "#dddddd")
      (mouse-color      . "black"))
      (isearch                       ((t (:inverse-video t  :underline t             ))))
      (lazy-highlight                ((t (:inverse-video t  :underline t             ))))
      (hl-line                       ((t (:background "gray13"                       ))))
      (fringe                        ((t (:background "#0d1b2b"                      ))))
      (mode-line                     ((t (:foreground "#bbbbbb" :background "#353e4b"))))
      (region                        ((t (:background "gray13"                       ))))
      (font-lock-builtin-face        ((t (:foreground "#9c56dc"                      ))))
      (font-lock-comment-face        ((t (:foreground "#187093"                      ))))
      (font-lock-function-name-face  ((t (:foreground "#edd400" :underline t         ))))
      (font-lock-keyword-face        ((t (:foreground "#b47113"                      ))))
      (font-lock-string-face         ((t (:foreground "#e65351"                      ))))
      (font-lock-type-face           ((t (:foreground "#3257d2"                      ))))
      (font-lock-constant-face       ((t (:foreground "#cc1e1e"                      ))))
      (font-lock-variable-name-face  ((t (:foreground "#cccccc"                      ))))                      
      (minibuffer-prompt             ((t (:foreground "#729fcf" :bold t              ))))
      (font-lock-warning-face        ((t (:foreground "#BB0000" :inverse-video t :underline "#bbbbbb" ))))
      )
   )
)

(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn 
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (custom-theme)))
```

However, in 24.3 now, for some reason when I open emacs in the terminal (emacs -nw), it's ignoring the background and foreground colors, so I get a white editor background regardless.  What's more, emacs is ignoring the -bg and -fg flags passed on the command line.

I've found that I can sort of force the colors on frame setup with something like this:

```
(defun on-after-init ()
  (unless (display-graphic-p (selected-frame))
    (progn
      (set-face-background 'default "black"   (selected-frame))
      (set-face-foreground 'default "#dddddd" (selected-frame)))))

(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'on-after-init)
```

But this feels like a hack, I'd like to understand why emacs isn't interpreting my color theme correctly.  My TERM is set to xterm-256color, though setting back to plain xterm doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Just a comment: Since there are two very different theme approaches, [Color Themes and Custom Themes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorAndCustomThemes), you might reconsider the name of your function (as it deals with color, not custom, themes).

Comment: @Drew fair enough, I stole that little snippet from someone else many moons ago so I'll just blame them =D